# Alternative for "so" as conjunction

Tags: word-choice, formality

Is there a better way of wording this sentence:

> Most of my colleagues and I have been affected by the coronavirus pandemic, **so** we're extra cautious.

The use of the word 'so' feels a tad suboptimal.

Comment: _therefore_/_as a result_...

Comment: *I would not use a contraction (we're) with a word like 'therefore'*.

Comment: I don't know if the word "myself" is being used correctly here. Consider "I."

Comment: @Dapianoman No it is not. "Myself" is a reflexive pronoun - *I did it myself*. For the subject of a sentence it needs to be "I" -  *I and most of my colleagues have...* Or better still *Most of my colleagues and I have...*

Comment: Why would *so* be "sub-optimal" or anything objectionable? Can you explain?

Comment: @Dapianoman The more common and conventional is *My colleagues and I ...* or *Me, as well as my colleagues ...*.

Comment: @Kris "Me, as well as my colleagues..." is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Dapianoman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me_and_My_Girl

Comment: @Dapianoman It would be grammatical, were it the object of the sentence e.g. *The company gave a bonus to me and my colleagues* but better *...to my colleagues and me*. Hence *me and my girl* is also grammatical if the object.

Comment: @WS2 Indeed as the object, but in this case we are discussing the subject of *x* and colleagues.

Comment: @Dapianoman Other than in my own comment, "subject" and "object" have not been used anywhere here. And that is critical to whether one employs "I" or "me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*hence*, *since then* or *now*, in a strictly temporal sense, rather superfluous.

In the example, *so* is not a logical conjunction. I do in fact not see an unambiguous logic behind the sentence. You could as well ommit any conjunction and have the same result, as far as the temporal correlation of events is concerned.

The eistemic implication is downright paradox: You have been affected, so it appears you generally aren't careful enough (which might be inevitable, and thus inevitably true, no offence).

That said, one might infer that you have taken notice and became so *much more careful*. But that's an odd, contracted way of saying it. Adding "therefore" does not help much at that, because the imolication is still embedded in the unwritten context.

Answer (score 1):

*Myself and most of my colleagues have been affected by the coronavirus pandemic, so we're extra cautious.*

If you *only* want to replace *'so'* in original sentence by an alternative conjunction:

*Myself and most of my colleagues have been affected by the coronavirus pandemic. Therefore, we're extra cautious.*

*(Instead of 'coronavirus', I'd use a more specific term. The term 'coronavirus' describes many viruses that share certain characteristics. The WHO name of the virus causing the current outbreak is COVID-19.)*

I'd write your sentence as:
***'Most of my colleagues and I have been affected by Covid-19. Therefore, we are now extra cautious.'***

Answer (score 1):

If you want to more closely associate the two ideas of the COVID-19 virus and the precautions, you could write: ***Most of my colleagues and I have been affected by COVID-19—we are now extra cautious.***

Answer (score 0):

I would have written:

Me, and most of my colleagues have been affected by the coronavirus pandemic; we are now being extra cautious.

Comment: Me have been affected....?